# How to join multiple consumers oracle AQ queue to regular queue? What am I doing wrong?

Tags: oracle, queue, oracle-aq

I tried to develop queueing mechanism for our application. My idea is to prepare standard solution where there is one application (app0) producing events and one or more applications (app1, app2) which consume them.
I need publisher/subscriber queue (topic), one queue for each consumer application and make regular queues subscribers of topic:

```
[app0] --enqueues-> [topic] <--subscribes-- [queue1] <--dequeues-- [app1]
                            <--subscribes-- [queue2] <--dequeues-- [app2]
```

I tried this:

```
DECLARE
    subscriber sys.aq$_agent;
    v_queue_name_topic VARCHAR2(200) := 'my_topic';
    v_queue_name_consumer_1 VARCHAR2(200) := 'my_consumer_1';
    v_queue_name_consumer_2 VARCHAR2(200) := 'my_consumer_2';
BEGIN
    DBMS_AQADM.CREATE_QUEUE_TABLE (queue_table => 't_' || v_queue_name_topic, queue_payload_type => 'SYS.AQ$_JMS_OBJECT_MESSAGE', multiple_consumers => true);
    DBMS_AQADM.CREATE_QUEUE (queue_name => v_queue_name_topic, queue_table => 't_' || v_queue_name_topic);
    DBMS_AQADM.START_QUEUE (queue_name => v_queue_name_topic);
    
    DBMS_AQADM.CREATE_QUEUE_TABLE (queue_table => 't_' || v_queue_name_consumer_1, queue_payload_type => 'SYS.AQ$_JMS_OBJECT_MESSAGE', multiple_consumers => false);
    DBMS_AQADM.CREATE_QUEUE (queue_name => v_queue_name_consumer_1, queue_table => 't_' || v_queue_name_consumer_1);
    DBMS_AQADM.START_QUEUE (queue_name => v_queue_name_consumer_1);
    
    DBMS_AQADM.CREATE_QUEUE_TABLE (queue_table => 't_' || v_queue_name_consumer_2, queue_payload_type => 'SYS.AQ$_JMS_OBJECT_MESSAGE', multiple_consumers => false);
    DBMS_AQADM.CREATE_QUEUE (queue_name => v_queue_name_consumer_2, queue_table => 't_' || v_queue_name_consumer_2);
    DBMS_AQADM.START_QUEUE (queue_name => v_queue_name_consumer_2);
    
    subscriber := sys.aq$_agent('Consumer1', v_queue_name_consumer_1, null);
    DBMS_AQADM.ADD_SUBSCRIBER(queue_name => v_queue_name_topic, subscriber => subscriber, queue_to_queue => true);
    
    subscriber := sys.aq$_agent('Consumer2', v_queue_name_consumer_2, null);
    DBMS_AQADM.ADD_SUBSCRIBER(queue_name => v_queue_name_topic, subscriber => subscriber);
    
    DBMS_AQADM.SCHEDULE_PROPAGATION(queue_name => v_queue_name_topic); 
END;
```

I wrote this code based on the only one example I found: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A87860_01/doc/appdev.817/a76938/adq_aex4.htm

It seems good, but unfortunately doesn't work. I tried to mess up a little bit with adding subscribers and a little bit with scheduling propagation. Nothing helped.

I expect this solution to pass messages from topic to queue1 and queue2, but messages are not passed. They stay in original queue.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: how are you consuming the messages in the queue ? I don't see any part in your code for running the  `dequeue` part

Comment: I expect 'propagation' will do the job dequeueing from topic and enqueueing into regular queues. Am I wrong?I'm going to use java application to consume messages from regular queues.

Answer (score -1):

May be because, you are using very old doc for Queue creation. Oracle now has reached 20c. The one in market now is 19c. Kindly use the below doc for your reference.

Click [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/adque/index.html)

Comment: I'll take a look, Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, but it seems I use proper API and procedures for this task. It didn't almost change.